# Passing php variables on click without refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables

**The problem:**

I have a series of 'accept' buttons, on click it opens a lightbox (a modal- using bootstrap), of course this is done without refreshing the page.

On the lightbox I need to show information regarding what is being accepted (therefore I need to pass a PHP variable to the lightbox). So the problem is how can I pass on a variable on click without refreshing the page? I tried using javascript, but the thing is once I set up a variable in JS I can't get that variable to PHP without refreshing the page.

The button has this code.

```
<a href="#modal-accept" data-toggle="modal"><button class="btn btn-acceptColor m-t-lg">Accept</button></a>
```

The other code isn't relevant for the purpose of this question. I just need the concept of how to actually do it.

Any help!?

Comment: @tymeJV thought so, I'm not that familiar with it though, do you have any examples of how to do it with AJAX?

Comment: see examples http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

there are many examples.
I provides some links, you can use them in your code as you suitability..

1). [Ajax Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257110/ajax-tutorial)
2). [jQuery Ajax POST example with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php/18714857#18714857)
3). [jQuery Ajax POST example with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)
4). [show data in lightbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065285/show-data-in-lightbox) 
5). [How to add jquery lightbox to content added to page via ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849394/how-to-add-jquery-lightbox-to-content-added-to-page-via-ajax)

I hope above links helpful for you

```
       $(".btn-acceptColor").click( function (){
        var person = {
        name: $("#id-name").val(),
        address:$("#id-address").val(),
        phone:$("#id-phone").val()
    }

$.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "exaple.php",
                  data: person,
                  success: function(msg) {
                      var msg = $.parseJSON(msg);
                      if(msg.success=='yes')
                      {
                         return true;
                       // fill you light-box form get value from example.php page 
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        alert('Server error');
                        return false;
                    }
                   }
            });
       });
```

Comment: yes if you provides some detail regarding to your question ...         second thing is that where your actually data exist on server or your loaded page ..?